# append with ajax call on table not clearing previous data in jquery php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, append

> I am working with jquery and php to get dynamic data with ajax call
>   into table format. I have one select option where i can choose
>   different companies.Onselect i will get some data of particular
>   employee with ajax i am binding that data to table.  But problem is if
>   i choose company 1 then i can able to bind data of company 1. onchange
>   company 2 data of company 1 should be disappear and company 2's data
>   only be there. but in my condition onchange company 2 previous data is
>   still there.

Below is my ajax call code:

```
 $.ajax({

          method: "GET",
           dataType: 'json',
           url:"getdata.php?id="+emp_id,
              success:function (response){
                     $.each(response, function( index, value ) {

                              $("table.table").append("<tr><td>" + response.emp_name + "</td><td>"  + "</td><td><input type='file'></td></tr>");

                      });
              },  
      });
```

Below is my html:

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you use `append` on success of getting data, you must clear the data on your table or else it will only add data below.

**ON YOUR HTML**

> Set attr id to your `<tbody>` tag:

```
 <tbody = "bodytable">
```

**ON YOUR SCRIPT**

> add code to clear the data on your `<tbody>`

```
          $("bodytable").empty();

 $.each(response, function( index, value ) {

      $("table.table").append("<tr><td>" + response.emp_name + "</td><td>"  + "</td><td><input type='file'></td></tr>");

      });
```

There are many ways to do that. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should empty your table first before appending content. Like below:

```
success:function (response){
    $("table.table").find('tbody').empty();
        $.each(response, function( index, value ) {
             $("table.table").find('tbody').append("<tr><td>" + response.emp_name + "</td><td>"  + "</td>    <td><input type='file'></td></tr>");
    });
}.
```

Also you should append in table tbody. Hope it helps you.